# jQuery autocomplete list item icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete and I want to add a font-awesome icon on the right side of all list items from the autocomplete source.

The solutions I found so far were setting the background of every list item but I want the font-awesome icon to listen for a click event so that doesn't help me.

This is my code:

```
            var data = ["a", "b", "c"];

            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: data,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).autocomplete("widget").css({
                        "width": $(this).parent().width()
                    });
                }
            });
```

In this case I would like to have a font-awesome icon on the right side of "a", "b" and "c"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code solved the problem for me:

```
        var data = ["a", "b", "c"];

        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: data,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).autocomplete("widget").css({
                    "width": $(this).parent().width()
                });
            }
        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
            .append("<div>" + item.label + "<span style='float: right'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span></div>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another simple way to add an image or font-awesome icon before an autocomplete list item.
    Step 1 - Open jquery.ui.js file
    Step 2 - Replace the following code

```
            _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                .append( $( "<div>" ).text( item.label ) )
                .appendTo( ul );
            },

           to

          _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
             return $( "<li>" )
            .append( $( "<div>" ).html(item.label+"<span style='float: right'><img src='images/trash.png'></span>" ))
            .appendTo( ul );
         },
                    or
         _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
        .append( $( "<div>" ).html( item.label+"<span style='float: right'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span>" ) )
        .appendTo( ul );
        },
```